# Nodejs to call webservice

Tags: jquery, node.js, angularjs, backbone.js

How to call the webservice using node.js.Is it possible to call websevice using node.js. If anyone know this explain with sample program and How to return the value from the webservice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Too broad. What have you tried ? Go read some nodejs doc/tutorials.

Comment: The "sample code writing service" is currently out of office.

Comment: @Bixi actually i am very new to this. Not much document is also available for node.js. Anyway i ll try jgillich example.Thanks for ur response.

Comment: you're kidding ? https://www.google.com/search?q=nodejs+tutorial

Answer (score 3):

Put the following in a file with the `.js` extension:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
  }
})
```

Now install the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library in the same folder using:

```
npm install request
```

Then run the file:

```
node file.js
```

Now you should see the contents of Google printed on your console.

Comment: i got it thanks. And how to print the value in webpage.

Comment: Take a look at express, a very popular framework for web-based applications in node: http://expressjs.com/guide.html